# Updating Injustice crashes my PS3

Tags: ps3, technical-issues, injustice-gods-among-us

My 1.08 version of Injustice won't install on my PS3. It just beeps and reboots the console. There's plenty of memory and it wouldn't install after the latest system update which it made me do before I could do the injustice one. My other games work fine. Don't know what else to try?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I just continued without updating and in the game main menu, I tried to sign in to PSN. It asked me for the update again and this time it worked. Downloading right now.

Answer (score -1):

The way I got it to work was to go to the game in ps3 menu, press triangle for options then checked for updates